# Use a different catalog image than the featured image

Tags: custom-field, images, post-thumbnails, woocommerce-offtopic

I have googled for well, hours now looking for a solution.

Its simple:

I dont want the catalog image to be the product featured image. I want it to be a custom image.

To partially achieve this, I installed the ACF plugin which allows me to add an image field to each product.

The issue now is, how to override the default feature image from loading in the catalog and use the custom image field.

Using wordpress, with woocommerce, and ACF plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the code for `the featured image` in template file with `custom field image` from Advanced Custom Field of the woocommerce product catalogue.